# Functions of 2 variables differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to figure out if the following functions from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable.

$$
  f(x,y) = (xy)^{\frac{1}{3}}
  $$
  $$
  f(x,y) =  \begin{cases} (x^2+y^2)\cdot\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right), &\mbox{if} \ (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
  0, &\mbox{if} \ (x,y) = (0,0)\\   \end{cases}
  $$

I would need a solid argument as to why they arent differentiable. This is done in relation to the theorem that states that if a function has partial derivatives of all variables and they are continuous in all points of the domain then the function is differentiable.

However, I'm quite sure that a function isnt required to have continuous partial derivatives to be differentiable, so I dont think I can use the theorem to prove if they arent differentiable. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Right, that the partial derivatives are continuous is sufficient but not necessary for differentiability. However, if a function is differentiable at a point, then all directional derivatives exist at that point. Can you use that criterion? (for one of the two examples? for both?)

Comment: I could imagine that would be useful looking at the 2nd function. I get the criterion you're stating but I'm not entirely sure what exact expression I should take the limit of when attempting it.

Comment: Say you want the directional derivative at $(x_0,y_0)$ in the direction $(u,v)$. Then you look at the difference quotients $$\frac{f(x_0 + tu, y_0 + tv) - f(x_0,y_0)}{t}$$ for $t\neq 0$. If the limit as $t\to 0$ doesn't exist (in $\mathbb{R}$; $\pm\infty$ is not a valid limit here), you know that $f$ isn't differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$. If the limit exists for all $(u,v)$, then you don't know, it might be differentiable, or it might not be.